# KendoReact Scheduler custom rendering

Tags: reactjs, telerik, kendo-react-ui

Given this [Scheduler](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/scheduler/) component, that I would like to configure to render the render the title with an Icon.

The [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-m9mkdd?file=src%2Fevents-utc.ts) demo contains this json:

```
{
    TaskID: 68,
    OwnerID: 1,
    RoomID: 2,
    Title: 'Breakfast with Tom',
    Description: '',
    StartTimezone: null,
    Start: '2024-01-23T09:45:00.000Z',
    End: '2024-01-23T11:30:00.000Z',
    EndTimezone: null,
    RecurrenceRule: null,
    RecurrenceID: null,
    RecurrenceException: null,
    isAllDay: false,
}
```

I would like something like this for the title:

```
"<i class="fa fa-cloud"></i> Breakfast with Tom"
```

As I see there is no built in solution for it.
The desired result is like this:
[image]
Is this somehow possible with this component?